# R - Optimizing loop operation on long table format

Tags: r, optimization, foreach, dplyr

I have a long format table data containing around 1.2 million rows in the below format

```
+-----------+-------+
| ProcessId | Event |
+-----------+-------+
|       111 | A     |
|       111 | B     |
|       111 | C     |
|       111 | D     |
|       111 | E     |
|       112 | A     |
|       112 | B     |
|       112 | D     |
|       112 | E     |
|       113 | A     |
|       113 | B     |
|       113 | C     |
|       113 | D     |
|       113 | E     |
+-----------+-------+
```

The events are already sorted by their time-stamp and I want to generate the process flow string for each process id from the long format table into a separate column to another table like below

processflow <- ('A->B->C->D->E' , 'A->B->D->E' ,'A->B->C->D->E' ,..etc)

I tried the below lines of code. but each of them is taking almost 850 seconds in my core i3, 4GB RAM laptop. what are the alternative ways to do this faster ?
Any guidance will be helpful

**Version 1 using dplyr package**

```
state_flow_identifier <- function(x){
y <-filter(data_longformat,process_id==x)
y_v <- as.vector(y$Event)
as.character(paste(y_v,collapse = '->'))
}

processflow_detection <- mutate(processflow_detection,processflow = apply(processflow_detection['process_id'],1,function(x)state_flow_identifier(x)))
```

**Version 2 using foreach package**

```
processflow <- foreach(i=processflow_detection$process_id,.combine='c') %do% state_flow_identifier(i)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this with `dplyr` and it's `group_by` function:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(ProcessId) %>%
  summarise(eventFlow = paste(Event, collapse = ' -> '))
```

Output will be as follows:

```
Source: local data frame [3 x 2]

  ProcessId             eventFlow
      (dbl)                 (chr)
1       111 A -> B -> C -> D -> E
2       112 A -> B -> C -> D -> E
3       113 A -> B -> C -> D -> E
```

Note, I used this data frame as input since your's was not in a format to input into R:

```
df <- data.frame(ProcessId = c(rep(111, 5), rep(112, 5), rep(113, 5)), Event = rep(c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'), 3))
df
   ProcessId Event
1        111     A
2        111     B
3        111     C
4        111     D
5        111     E
6        112     A
7        112     B
8        112     C
9        112     D
10       112     E
11       113     A
12       113     B
13       113     C
14       113     D
15       113     E
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.  your answer helped me to reduce execution time to less than 10 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

You should also check out `data.table` for efficiency, (Using @Gopala's data frame)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(event_flow = paste(Event, collapse = '->')), by = ProcessId]
#   ProcessId    event_flow
#1:       111 A->B->C->D->E
#2:       112 A->B->C->D->E
#3:       113 A->B->C->D->E
```

Comment: thanks got system.time output for your answer 0.47 secs. For @Gopala's answer the command running time was more or less the same (0.49). since I already marked his reply as answered.. I am leaving it like that :-).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any libraries.

```
df <- data.frame(ProcessId=c(rep(111,5),rep(112,4),rep(113,5)),Event=unlist(strsplit("ABCDEABDEABCDE","")))
len <- nrow(df)
new_process_id <- c(TRUE, df$ProcessId[-len] != df$ProcessId[-1])
sym <- rep(" -> ", len)
sym[new_process_id] <- ","
str <- paste(sym, df$Event, sep="", collapse="")
data.frame(ProcessId=rle(df$ProcessId)$val,EventFlow=unlist(strsplit(str,","))[-1])
```

Output:

```
  ProcessId             EventFlow
1       111 A -> B -> C -> D -> E
2       112      A -> B -> D -> E
3       113 A -> B -> C -> D -> E
```

For 1.25 mln lines, the execution time was about 2 seconds on my laptop

Comment: The actual exection time for his code was less than a second. The entire ETL time was brought down to less than 10 seconds. My bad, I was not explicit. However thanks for the inputs.